# Mathematical proof of tradeoff between estimation error and computation cost in mini-batch gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, gradient-descent, artificial-intelligence

> **" with more examples, the estimate would have a lower standard error,
>   but the return is less than linear compared to the computational
>   burden we incur."**

Came across this line while studying one of the papers. It basically mentions that the **number of examples** from data used for gradient calculation and the **error in the gradient estimation** as the number of data points is **less than linearly related**.

How can one prove this mathematically?